# Playwright: Is there a way to watch to see if element becomes visible

Tags: e2e-testing, playwright

Is there a way to watch for the visibility of an element similar to how `waitForRequest` works - https://playwright.dev/docs/api/class-page#page-wait-for-request

The problem I'm trying to solve is a flaky test that checks that a loading spinner has been displayed. In some cases the loading spinner is displayed and hidden so quickly that the `expect(element).toBeVisible()` runs when the element has already hidden itself again.

I can see in the trace that immediately after the click the element is visible but has hidden by the time the expect runs.

Comment: Using toBeVisible for spinner is plain wrong. See - https://stackoverflow.com/a/76715586

Comment: @VishalAggarwal if you want to check that your spinner is appearing when requests are running there is no other option than to use `toBeVisible`. What you are advocating is not testing your spinner.

Comment: What I am advocating is to verify 'determistic' functional behavior e.g. after filling a form and submitting it , verify that newly added order generates a new order ID which can be queried instead of spinner which may not appear at all in case of good application performance.

Comment: I think the point you are missing is there is no guarantee that spinner will appear every time , in case when application performance is super good e.g in night time when there are no users.

Comment: @VishalAggarwal unless you control the request\response as I have done in my answer here https://stackoverflow.com/a/77122391/833910

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Initially I did use unickq's answer but even this has failed on occassion. Here is the most robust solution I have found.

Mock the route that the spinner is appearing for and only `fufill` the request when you have asserted if the spinner is visible.
https://playwright.dev/docs/mock#modify-api-responses

```
test('check spinner appears', () => {
    await page.route('*/**/api/v1/spinner-is-visible-until-i-resolve', async route => {
        expect(spinner).toBeVisible();
        await route.fulfill();
    });
    await makeApiRequestButton.click();
});
```

If you want more actions and assertions in your test you can add a promise so the test doesn't run on before the spinner has been checked.

```
test('check spinner appears', () => {
    let gateResolve;
    const gatePromise = new Promise((resolve) => {
        gateResolve = resolve;
    });
    await page.route('*/**/api/v1/spinner-is-visible-until-i-resolve', async route => {
        expect(spinner).toBeVisible();
        await route.fulfill();
        gateResolve();
    });
    await makeApiRequestButton.click();
    await gatePromise;
    // do something else now the spinner has gone
});
```

Answer (score 3):

If you're sure that expect is not fast enough - try to wrap it into Promise.all, so it will wait for the spinner before clicking.

```js
await button.click();
await expect(spinner).toBeVisible();
```

```js
await Promise.all([expect(spinner).toBeVisible(), button.click()]);
```

See a long explanation of how it works [here](https://github.com/microsoft/playwright/issues/5470#issuecomment-1285640689).

As an alternative - use [noWaitAfter](https://playwright.dev/docs/api/class-locator#locator-click-option-no-wait-after).

```js
await button.click({ noWaitAfter: true });
```

Comment: The "long explanation" using `waitForResponse`. I was looking for a similar thing but for element visibility e.g. `waitForVisible`. You can't use them interchangably. In what you have posted the `toBeVisible` does execute before the `click` and there is nothing but timeouts preventing this from failing.

Answer (score 1):

If the element hides too fast, why not use slow mode and run your expect tests?

```
// Slow by 100 milliseconds per operation
await chromium.launch({ headless: false, slowMo: 100 }); 

// add your logic
...expect(element).toBeVisible()
```

See [link](https://playwright.dev/docs/debug#headed-mode)